# How do I handle password prompting as-needed for Gradle build?

Tags: gradle

I have a fairly complex Gradle build process, one step of which requires communication with a service, for which I need a special token file. I can generate this token file just fine manually, but I'd like to add it to my build so that, if the token file is not present, the user is prompted for their credentials.

I have referenced the following blog post about this: https://www.timroes.de/2014/01/19/using-password-prompts-with-gradle-build-files/, but it is missing a small detail for me. I do not want to unconditionally prompt the user for their credentials; I only want to prompt them if the token file needs to be created.

Let's say I have the following task:

```groovy
task createToken(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn userCredentialPrompt
    outputs.file 'creds.token'
    environment 'USERNAME', project.username
    environment 'PASSWORD', project.password
    executable './create_token_file'
}

task somethingRequiringToken {
    dependsOn: createToken
    inputs.file 'creds.token'
    // Other task-specific configuration here.
}
```

And the `userCredentialPrompt` task is one that prompts the user for their credentials and assigns the `project.username` and `project.password` to the correct values (using logic like the linked blog post above).

The problem here is that both the username and password are null. I'm pretty sure I understand the reason why. They're set at configuration time, but the prompt for user credentials takes place at execution time. That said, I don't know the right way to get Gradle to behave so that the following happens:

- When `somethingRequiringToken` is executed, if the `creds.token` file is missing, it runs `createToken`.
- When `somethingRequiringToken` is executed, if the `creds.token` file is present, the `createToken` task is not executed.
- When `createToken` is executed, the user is prompted for their credentials.
- When the user credentials are acquired, they are passed (reasonably securely) to an external executable that generates the `creds.token` file.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand, what is the question? That _username_ and _password_ are null? Can you please share a `build.gradle` that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Opal I understand why the username and password are null. I just don't know how to move the configuration-time setting of the environment variables to run-time, preserving the ability of the task to run only as needed. Essentially the question is, "How do I get Gradle to behave according to the behavior in the four bullet points I've written?"